# Monodroid: Set imageview image from file in assets or Resources/drawable to configure SampleSize

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I want so set the samplesize of my image before I set it to the `imageview`. The problem is, that my application crashes if I set the image directly to `imageview`. (because needs too much memory!?)

Here's my code:

```
ImageView iv = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imagePusher);
Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options options = new Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options();
options.InSampleSize = 2;

Android.Graphics.Bitmap bMap = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeFile("the_path_I_want_to_know/image.jpg", options);

iv.SetImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Comment: I can't say I'm very profficient with monodroid, but it's not like MT. You need to use `Asset.Open` to get the file stream, and change the build action to AndroidAsset for you to get direct access to the file stream of the image in your case.

Comment: Yes I know the Asset.Open method, but know how I can set the samplesize with the filestream, because the BitmapFactory.DecodeFile method does only accept a filepath

Comment: In a previous project I used `BitmapFactory.DecodeStream` instead.

Comment: Yes thank you but I can't that the BitmapFactory Options with the samplesize there. Should I use the compress method instead of the samplesize?

Comment: The API [has an overload](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Graphics.BitmapFactory%2fM%2fDecodeStream) that you can pass options into it.

Comment: Ah sorry I was wrong, the method accepts 3 parameters incl. the Options, I will test it, thank you

Comment: Yes I will write the answer down after 8 hours, because my reputation is too low to answer it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Candide for help, now it works with the following code:

```
ImageView iv = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imagePusher);

Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options options = new Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options();
options.InSampleSize = 2;

Stream bitmap = Assets.Open("myimage.jpg");

Android.Graphics.Bitmap bMap = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(bitmap, null, options);


iv.SetImageBitmap(bMap);
```